# C# XOR Encrypted Text Is Not Shown on RichTextBox

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding, xor

I've been working on bitwise operators, and then tried to encode some text with XOR operator. It works but the encrypted text doesn't show up on richTextBox. Researched about encodings but I didn't get anywhere so far.

Code works when I dont use any control and use directly strings.

```
string computehash(string text, string pass)
    {
        string encrypted = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            encrypted +=Convert.ToChar(text[i] ^ pass[i % pass.Length]);
        }
        return encrypted;
    }
```

Comment: Think about what XOR does, and then imagine that the first character of the password is equal to that of the first character of the plaintext.

Comment: and ? what did you mean ?

Comment: I think you need to understand a bit about character encoding before continuing. Please lookup an ASCII table or something.

Answer (score 4):

Xoring the numeric value of two chars does not necessarily produce a char that can be displayed. You should probably "encrypt" bytes, not chars.

Display the encrypted binary data as hex or base64. Or, as base2 so that you can see the XOR at work.